# How to get filename of subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

How to get the filename of the subclass?

Example:

`base.py`:

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # How to get the path "./main1.py"?
```

`main1.py`:

```
from base import BaseClass

class MainClass1(BaseClass):
    pass
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186535/discussion-on-question-by-e-info128-how-to-get-filename-of-subclass).

Answer (score 9):

Remember that `self` in `BaseClass.__init__` is an instance of the actual class that's being initialised. Therefore, one solution, is to ask that class which module it came from, and then from the path for that module:

```
import importlib

class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        m = importlib.import_module(self.__module__)
        print m.__file__
```

I think there are probably a number of way you could end up with a module that you can't import though; this doesn't feel like the most robust solution.

If all you're trying to do is identify where the subclass came from, then probably combining the module name and class name is sufficient, since that *should* uniquely identify it:

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print "{}.{}".format(
            self.__module__,
            self.__class__.__name__
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by reaching back through the calling stack to get the global namespace of the caller of the `BaseClass.__init__()` method, and from that you can extract the name of the file it is in by using the value of the `__file__` key in that namespace.

Here's what I mean:

`base.py`:

```
import sys

class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('In BaseClass.__init__()')
        callers_path = sys._getframe(1).f_globals['__file__']
        print('  callers_path:', callers_path)
```

`main1.py`:

```
from base import BaseClass

class MainClass1(BaseClass):
    def __init(self):
        super().__init__()

mainclass1 = MainClass1()
```

Sample output of running `main1.py`:

```
In BaseClass.__init__()
  callers_path: the\path\to\main1.py
```

Comment: Thanks but python print the 3r level of components: (index.py) without the `MainClass1`. But your response works with the example but not with my project. Thanks anyway. The MainClass1 is called dinamicaly using `importlib.util`.

Comment: It's possible to reach back more than one level of the call stack, so I think it would be possible to handle your situation. If you modify the code in your question to match your real code, I may be able to show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to the wrong mechanism for your solution.  Your comments suggest that what you want is an exception handler with minimal trace-back capability.  This is not something readily handled within the general `class` mechanism.

Rather, you should look into Python's stack inspection capabilities.  Very simply, you want your `__init__` method to report the file name of the calling sub-class.  You can hammer this by requiring the caller to pass its own `__file__` value.  In automated fashion, you can dig back one stack frame and access `__file__` via that context record.  Note that this approach *assumes* that the only time you need this information is when `__init__` is called is directly from a sub-class method.

Is that enough to get you to the right documentation?